# ol3 reset to draw interaction mode if coordinates intersect

Tags: draw, openlayers, openlayers-3, intersection

```
this.drawInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({ 
        features: this.sourceFeatures,
        type: 'Polygon', 
        geometryFunction: (coords, geom) => this.onDrawGeometryFunction(coords, geom) 
    });

private onDrawGeometryFunction(coords, geom): void {
    if (!geom) {
        geom = new ol.geom.Polygon(null);
    } 
    if (coords[0].length !== this.coords_length) {
        //if intersects undo last point 
        if (this.intersectionsExistInPolygon(coords[0])) { 
            this.drawInteraction.removeLastPoint();
            return geom;
        }
        this.coords_length = coords[0].length;        
    }
     geom.setCoordinates(coords);
    return geom;
}
```

I can able to identify the intersection until I click on the starting point to complete the draw(by connecting through the drawn line). Is there a way to listen the draw complete(but not the 'drawend') before it happen? to keep the draw mode active by removing the intersecting last point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was using Openlayers@v3.14.2 this finishcondition is available from v3.16.0. So I had to update only the version it worked fine..